# Create new Image from 2 diferent images C#

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

I am working in a function where I have two images, one of them is the backgroud and the other one is a QR code, I need create a new image using the background(image 1) and the QR image, but I need define the position of the QRCode Image. 
like the bellow image,
[image]

best regards

Comment: You have to show your attempted code and what isn't working.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a really lazy "program for me, StackOverflow" question.

Comment: @Nyerguds I review my question but I am no able to find the phrase, hey can you code for me?, I ask I am working, I ask info about  how I can do that,(paper, libraries, etc), thanks for your comment

Comment: @ClaudioGareca, if you found a working solution, then please don't edit it into the question (that breaks Q&A format), rather post another answer. Self-answers are very welcomed (if they help future readers). Also consider to accept (mark) either of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
using (Image background = Image.FromFile("background.jpg"))
using (Image qrCode = Image.FromFile("qrCode.jpg"))
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(background))
{
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;
    graphics.DrawImage(qrCode, x, y);
    background.Save("result.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Honestly though, this question shows a complete lack of research.

Comment: many thanks @Paviel it help me to improve my last code, best regards